# Error while Integrating Camera to MS Access

Tags: windows, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I got the code from :

https://www.developerfusion.com/thread/46191/how-to-capture-picture-using-webcam-in-vb60/

However while using this code I got an compilation error>

The code in this project must be updated for use on 64-bit systems. Please review and update Declare Statements and then mark them with PtrSafe attribute.

I used :

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal ms As LongPtr)
#Else
    Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal ms as Long)
#End If
```

It doesnt work.

Comment: Iv tried using:  #If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal ms As LongPtr)
#Else
    Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal ms as Long)
#End If

Answer (score 1):

The conditional compilation (`#If VBA7`) is not necessary unless your DB needs to run on`Office 2007`or lower. If oldest version is`Office 2010`you just need

```vb
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal ms As Long)
```

because`VBA7`converts`LongPtr`to data-type`Long`on Office x86 and to`LongLong`on Office x64.

Recognize the argument`ms`stays a`Long`as it is no Pointer/Handle. See [How to convert Windows API declarations in VBA for 64-bit](https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=windows-api-declaration-vba-64-bit) for more information.

If you need to support old Office-Versions before VBA7 use:

```vb
#If VBA7 Then
  Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal ms As Long)
#Else
  Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal ms as Long)
#End If
```